# My yellow Zucchini flowers are closed

Tags: plant-health, growth, zucchini

I have a Zucchini plant. The flowers were open a couple of days ago. Now they stay closed. The females are very small and have not grown much. Should I prune the plant and hope the new growth will have flowers that open?

Comment: Flowers only stay open a few days at most. Not sure what you expect here, but this sounds perfectly normal - both types of flowers will shrivel away, if the females got pollinated the fruit will grow, (but not noticeably in "a few days") if not the proto-fruit at their base will shrivel as well. More flowers will happen all by themselves in the normal course of zucchini.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Today I had two mail flowers open but no female. I think I will have to self-polinate as I haven't seen many Bees around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plucking off the flowers should stimulate more flower production. The flowers are edible. You shouldn't need to prune the green parts of the plant. The male flowers don't usually last very many days.